# Same moment syntax with similar looking dates give radically different result

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Code:

```
  console.log(form.createdAt);
  console.log(form.updatedAt);
  console.log(typeof form.createdAt);
  console.log(typeof form.updatedAt);

  form.startedAt = moment(form.createdAt).format("MMMM D, YYYY hh:mm A");
  form.finishedAt = moment(form.updatedAt).format("MMMM D, YYYY hh:mm A");

  console.log(form.startedAt);
  console.log(form.finishedAt);
```

Output:

```
2020-03-01T23:07:30.677Z
2020-03-01T23:12:32.382Z
object
object
March 1, 2020 04:07 PM
2020-03-01T23:12:00.000Z
```

How is this possible?

Update: 
Moment version is:     `"moment": "^2.24.0"`

Comment: I just tested it here and it seems to be working fine - https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-volhard-ntvdz - Odd.

Comment: I know, usually as I zero in on something I see the error in what I'm doing, this is one of the first times it seems impossible lol

Comment: Can you add the browser and version you are getting these results?
Does this happen on multiple browsers?

Comment: This is on a Node backend @EduardoLelis